# Populate Navigation Bar based from Login using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem and I don't know if this is the correct forum.

I have to create a system using ASP.NET Core MVC and the system have 10 plans. And in order to know the plan it will be based on the login.

And this is the sample navigation bar for (there will be lots of navigation bar and only some can be found for some plans like the order and report).

Plan 1

```
a.  Orders
b.  Reprint Receipt
c.  Report
d.  Setting
```

Plan 2

```
a.  Orders
b.  Buy
c.  Report
d.  Setting
```

Plan 3

```
a.  Orders
b.  Buy
c.  Cancel Purchase
```

There are 10 plans and some have different navigations (redirects to a different page).

My plan is to create the pages for each plan.

But how can I populate the navigation bar for each plan?

I don't want to have many if statement in the view to hide some navigation bar for each plan.

How can I solve this? I'm thinking of having a config file. Then after the login read the config file in order to know the navigation for each plan.

Is this a correct solution for this? Or is there a better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the navigation menu, first, I suggest you create a NavigationModel model to store the navigation text and the url, the NavigationModel model as below:

```
public class NavigationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NavigationName { get; set; }
    public string NavigationUrl { get; set; }
    public string PlanType { get; set; }
}
```

And the following DataRepository contains the test data, in your application, you could store the data into database, then get the navigations via the DbContext:

```
public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    public List<NavigationModel> GetNavigations()
    {
        return new List<NavigationModel>()
        {
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1001, NavigationName="Orders", NavigationUrl="Home/Orders", PlanType="Plan1"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1002, NavigationName="Reprint Receipt", NavigationUrl="Home/Reprint", PlanType="Plan1"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1003, NavigationName="Report", NavigationUrl="Home/Report", PlanType="Plan1"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1004, NavigationName="Setting", NavigationUrl="Home/Setting", PlanType="Plan1"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1005, NavigationName="Orders", NavigationUrl="Home/Orders", PlanType="Plan2"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1006, NavigationName="Buy", NavigationUrl="Home/Buy", PlanType="Plan2"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1007, NavigationName="Report", NavigationUrl="Home/Report", PlanType="Plan2"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1008, NavigationName="Setting", NavigationUrl="Home/Setting", PlanType="Plan2"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =1009, NavigationName="Orders", NavigationUrl="Home/Orders", PlanType="Plan3"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =10010, NavigationName="Buy", NavigationUrl="Home/Buy", PlanType="Plan3"},
            new NavigationModel(){ Id =10011, NavigationName="Cancel Purchase", NavigationUrl="Home/CancelPurchase", PlanType="Plan3"},
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you could try to use the following methods to populate the navigation menu.

1. Use session to store the navigation information.

   First, [configure the application to use session and add the SessionExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state) (Note the session expired time)

   Second, after user login successfully, you could refer the following code to get the relate navigation menu, and store them in the session:

   ```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var isUserLogin = true;
        var plantype = "Plan2";

        if (isUserLogin && _dataRepository.GetNavigations().Any(c => c.PlanType.Contains(plantype)))
        {
            var navigations = _dataRepository.GetNavigations().Where(c => c.PlanType == plantype).ToList();

            if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<NavigationModel>>("Navigation") == default)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Set<List<NavigationModel>>("Navigation", navigations);
            }

        }
        return View();
    }
   ```

   In the _Layout.cshtml page, add the following code in the header:

   ```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    @inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
   ```

   [Note] In the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, use `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to register the HttpContextAccessor.

   Then, we could access the session and populate the navigation menu:

   ```
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li>
        @if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<NavigationModel>>("Navigation") != default)
        {
            var navigations = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<NavigationModel>>("Navigation");
            foreach (var item in navigations)
            {
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="@item.NavigationUrl">@item.NavigationName</a>
                </li>
            }

        }
    </ul>
   ```
2. Use JQuery Ajax to call the action method and populate the navigation menu:

   In the Home Controller, create an action method to get the navigation menu:

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetNavigation(string plantype)
    { 
        //check if user login and get the relate navigation menus.
        return Json(_dataRepository.GetNavigations().Where(c => c.PlanType == plantype).ToList());
    }
   ```

   In the _Layout.cshtml page, use the following code to add the navigation menu:

   ```
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/GetNavigation",
                method: "Post",
                data: { "plantype": "Plan2" },
                success: function (items) { 
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.setAttribute('class', 'nav-item');

                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                        a.setAttribute('class', 'nav-link text-dark');
                        a.href = items[i].navigationUrl;
                        var linkText = document.createTextNode(items[i].navigationName);
                        a.appendChild(linkText); 

                        li.appendChild(a);

                        $(".navbar-nav")[0].appendChild(li);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
   ```

The result as below (display plan 2):

[image]